# Improve performance of slow running spark streaming process that uses micro-batching

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to create an application to process 10 million json files where the size of a json can vary from 1mb to 50mb.

To avoid burdening the driver I am using the structured streaming api to process 100,000 json files at a time rather than loading all the source files at once.

**mySchema**

```
 val mySchema: StructType = 
      StructType( Array(
        StructField("ID",StringType,true), 
        StructField("StartTime",DoubleType, true),
        StructField("Data", ArrayType(
          StructType( Array(
              StructField("field1",DoubleType,true),
              StructField("field2",LongType,true),
              StructField("field3",LongType,true),
              StructField("field4",DoubleType,true),
              StructField("field5",DoubleType,true),
              StructField("field6",DoubleType,true),
              StructField("field7",LongType,true),          
              StructField("field8",LongType,true)
              )),true),true)))
```

**Create Streaming Dataframe by picking 100,000 files at a time**

```
val readDF = spark.readStream
                    .format("json")
                    .option("MaxFilesPerTrigger", 100000)
                    .option( "pathGlobFilter", "*.json")
                    .option( "recursiveFileLookup", "true")
                    .schema(mySchema)
                    .load("/mnt/source/2020/*")
```

**writeStream to start streaming computation**

```
val sensorFileWriter = binaryDF
                      .writeStream
                      .queryName( "myStream")
                      .format("delta")
                      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("30 seconds"))
                      .outputMode("append")
                      .option( "checkpointLocation", "/mnt/dir/checkpoint")
                      .foreachBatch(
                        (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
                          
                          batchDF.persist()
                        
                          val parseDF = batchDF
                          .withColumn("New_Set", expr("transform(Data, x -> (x.field1 as f1, x.field2 as f2, x.field3 as field3))"))
                          .withColumn("Data_New",addCol(uuid(),to_json($"New_Set")))
                          .withColumn("data_size", size(col("Data")))
                          .withColumn("requestid", uuid())
                          .withColumn("start_epoch_double", bround($"StartTime").cast("long"))
                          .withColumn("Start_date", from_unixtime($"start_epoch_double", "YYYYMMdd"))
                          .withColumn("request", concat(lit("start"), col("Data_New"), lit("end")))
                          .persist()
                          
                          val requestDF = parseDF
                           .select($"Start_date", $"request")

                           requestDF.write
                            .partitionBy("Start_date")
                            .mode("append")
                            .parquet("/mnt/Target/request")
                      }
                        )
```

In the above "addCol" is a user defined function that adds new StructField to Array of StructFields

```
val addCol = udf((id:String,json:String) => {
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
    compact(parse(json).extract[List[Map[String,String]]].map(m => Map("requestid" -> id) ++ m))
})
```

"uuid" is another udf that generates a unique id

```
val uuid = udf(() => java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)
```

Databricks cluster Config:-

Apache Spark 2.4.5

70 Workers: 3920.0 GB Memory, 1120 Cores (i.e. 56.0 GB Memory and 16 Cores per Worker)

1 Driver: 128.0 GB Memory, 32 Cores

The below image is total tasks for writing each batch of 100,000 which takes more than an hour. The entire process takes days to complete processing the 10 million json files.

[image]

How can I make this streaming process run faster?

Should I be setting the property for "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions". If so what is a good value for this property?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you want a 1-to-1 mapping of partitions to cores for streaming applications...*Azure Databricks Structured Streaming.*

To optimize mapping of your partitions to cores, try this:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", sc.defaultParallelism)
```

This will give you a 1-to-1 mapping of your partitions to cores.

Comment: The stream query is still running slowly even after setting this property. 
Do I also have to set spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes? If you have any other suggestion let me know

Comment: Hi Did you find solution to this ? I am running in to similar issues where parsing of json making my streaming query extremely slow .